Minimum Number of Elements Required to Fulfill Conditions
Here is the problem:
Suppose there is a game with 4 rounds. Each round has 4 distinct teams of 2 players. Players can only play once in a round. Is there a way of placing 8 players, such that all players satisfy the following 2 conditions:

For each team, they play on it no more than once
For each other player, they play with them no more than once

throughout each of the 4 rounds.
If so, provide an example. If not, what is the minimum number of players to satisfy the conditions.
I verified that (1) alone is satisfiable by iteratively applying the Hungarian algorithm (likely not the intended solution). But am at a loss for where to start for the full problem, help!

Earlier, I asked a generalization of your question, where you allow any number of teams and any number of people per team. The question was only answered in special cases, including your case. Here is the schedule, which I found using the finite field over four elements, as I described in my answer to that earlier question.



${}$
Team 1
Team 2
Team 3
Team 4




Round 1
$ 1, 5 $
$ 2, 6 $
$ 3, 7 $
$ 4, 8 $


Round 2
$ 2, 7 $
$ 1, 8 $
$ 4, 5 $
$ 3, 6 $


Round 3
$ 4, 6 $
$ 3, 5 $
$ 2, 8 $
$ 1, 7 $


Round 4
$ 3, 8 $
$ 4, 7 $
$ 1, 6 $
$ 2, 5 $



